# Восстановление базы MS Office Access

Tags: access

Ребята, подскажите, пожалуйста, как восстановить базу? При запуске выходит ошибка.

> Процесс остановлен ядром базы данных Microsoft Jet, так как другой пользователь пытается оновременно изменить те же данные"

При этом к базе никто не подключен.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте открыть базу в режиме конструктора и сделать сжатие. Возможно сжатие окончится сообщением об ошибке. В этом случае в каталоге с исходной должна появиться еще одна база, с которой и попытайтесь работать. Прочтите рекрмендации : http://forum.vingrad.ru/forum/act-ST/f-159/t-383627/unread-1.htm P.S. Естественно, перед выполнением этих операций сделайте копию Вашей базы. P.S.S Панель управления -> Администрирование -> Источники данных ODBC -> User DSN -> БД MsAccess - > Восстановить.